# Calculate Average of Average got from each group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to calculate first child level averages at first on group level and then calculate the parent group level average

I have a database table below

[image]

```
SELECT
    Country, IndexType
    , NULLIF(CAST(AVG(NULLIF(CAST(IndexPoint AS FLOAT), 0)) AS NUMERIC(18,1)), 0) AS IndexPoint_ChildAverage 
FROM tbl_CountryIndex
GROUP BY Country,IndexType
```

I get below result from above query

[image]

My final and actual goal is to get average of averages from above query so that I get single result for USA that is average of 1.5 and 3.0 and that it 2.25

Any one can help me in getting this result so that I get 2.25 i.e. Average of  averages as shown below

[image]

Comment: I'd note that this calculation doesn't make much *sense* as it stands. You've got averages calculated across different population sizes (due to nulls being discarded). Averaging those produces a number, but that number doesn't really stand for anything.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Demien I think you are right. Averages of averages dont make any sense. It creates  ”Simpsons Paradox” and I am aware of that. I got this requirement from client and I highlighted that this requirement is not making sense. Client still insisted to do things this way. I did job both ways. Calculating the actual averages and this average of averages but this update is not yet deployed as this question is still under discussion if shall we use an average of averages or not

Comment: Dale when I copy/pasted data it. I wanted to paste it as simple text but stackflow almost forced me to post it as image and then instead of more trying I went for images. I tried couple of times and then gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery.  I don't see the need for all those conversions from one type to another, so:

```
SELECT country, AVG(IndexPoint_ChildAverage)
FROM (SELECT Country, IndexType, AVG(NULLIF(IndexPoint, 0) * 1.0) as IndexPoint_ChildAverage 
      FROM tbl_CountryIndex
      GROUP BY Country, IndexType 
     ) ci
GROUP BY Country;
```

If you want a particular type in the outer query, you can `cast()` the average to that type.

Comment: Isn't there a group by country missing in the last line?

Comment: Thanks. I modified it a bit so its works in the actual scenario and its working.